# phpMyAdmin wrong parameters

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I can't get phpmyadmin running with xampp:

*MySQL diu:*

No es pot connectar: paràmetres incorrectes.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una
>   conexi�n ya que el equipo de destino deneg� expresamente dicha
>   conexi�n.

La connexió de l'usuari de control ha fallat, tal com està definida ara a la configuració.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una
>   conexi�n ya que el equipo de destino deneg� expresamente dicha
>   conexi�n.

phpMyAdmin ha intentat connectar amb el servidor MySQL, però el servidor ha rebutjat la connexió. Comproveu l'amfitrió, el nom d'usuari i la contrasenya al vostre fitxer config.inc.php i assegureu-vos que correspon amb la informació facilitada per l'administrador del servidor MySQL.

I've tried editing the file config.inc.php but couldn't see what I should change.

Also haven't seen this problem anywhere else in google, so hope this isn't duplicate.

Any idea is welcomed,

Thank you in advance.

PD: my config.inc.php file main things:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
```

Comment: Please don't post an error message as an image.Post it as text.

Comment: It could be that your password is wrong. But we will never know it for sure :p

Comment: try `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'` instead of `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'` and remove `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306'`. Also by default root has no password in xammp, so it might not be the password.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin '$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'' was something I tried from another post that didn't work. Still the same doing what you said.

Comment: The error message does tell that the username or password is wrong, as far as my tranlstion tells me, so i guess either the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'` is wrong or `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''` is wrong. Note that the last one is empty string. The error replicates easyly when you set the wrong password in the config. Or an even better solution - check that your SQL server is running. You get that message when it is not running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. All I had to do was following this tutorial:

[set pswd to mysql.user](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/)

Also changed my config.inc.php with the newly setted pswd.

For further issues with this:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'new_password'; //new password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
```

Thankyou to all that tried helping me out.

Comment: Congrats on finding a solution. Didn't even think about that one. I ran into something similar long time ago.